# Android: pixelization of upscaled/downscaled resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-graphics

I have a problem with the "pixelization" of the embedded icons (`main/res`) on some devices. It can be reproduced on some Android 9 TV boxes and it happenes when an icon is upscaled/downscaled somehow (see images as example). But I do not know why it happens. And I can not reproduce this bug on any devices of mine and on any Android Emulator. I am using regular Android resources (`R.drawable`) in an XML layout. As I can see, it is not an anti-alias problem. Also, the same APK works great on the other TV boxes. This problem was reported by the user and as I said - I can not reproduce it. These resources were set just via `android:src` in `ImageView`, nothing special.

What I need to check first? Thanks.

Example of the pixelization:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/k76jx.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp8iX.png

**UPDATE:**

I tested this behavior with the user on his TV box: it happens only with SVG(VectorDrawable) graphics and with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` (it is true by default). If I set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` everything works as expected. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:resource="@7F160010" />
```